# How do I create a PHP array with 2 variables for each element without using an object?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array, key

I'm new to PHP and would require some assistance if possible.

I have the array

```
array("Name" => $userName, "Age" => $userAge);
```

This works for one user but lets say I wanted to add multiple users that will all have a Name and Age how would I do that? Instead of passing is `$userName` would I have to pass it an array of user names and instead of `$userage` an array of user ages hence making it multidimesional?

Also for my purposes I cannot put the username and userage in an object and then simply add it to the array.

Answer (score 3):

One way is:

```
array(
    array("Name" => $userName, "Age" => $userAge),
    array("Name" => $userName1, "Age" => $userAge1),
    array("Name" => $userName2, "Age" => $userAge2)
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code which should solve your problem given.  The two input array, names and ages, do not need to be the same size, and the output array will insert default values ('N/A' for names, -1 for ages) where a corresponding name or age is missing.

```
$userNames = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'];
$userAges = [26,14,99];
$userNamesAndAges = [];

for ($i=0; $i < max(count($userNames), count($userAges)); $i++) {
    if (isset($userNames[$i])) {
        $userName = $userNames[$i]; 
    } else {
        $userName = 'N/A';
    }

    if (isset($userAges[$i])) {
        $userAge = $userAges[$i];
    } else {
        $userAge = -1;
    }

    $userNamesAndAges[] = [
        'Name' => $userName,
        'Age' => $userAge
    ];
}

foreach ($userNamesAndAges as $obj) {
    $name = $obj['Name'];
    $age = $obj['Age'];
    echo("Name: $name, Age: $age<br>"); 
}
```

Outputs:

Name: name1, Age: 26
Name: name2, Age: 14
Name: name3, Age: 99
Name: name4, Age: -1

Answer (score 1):

Typecast the variables $userName and $userAge to array -

```
$userName = (array)$userName;
$userAge = (array)$userAge;
```

Iterate over them for further processing. It would then make no difference if the size of array was one or many.

Comment: How does this create an array of multiple users? It just makes an array of 1 user.